# Calling Python function from within function

Tags: python

I am attempting to call two_byte_proc(payload,offset) from within process() but it does not write to the output file out_buf. The output from offset or payload may contain None so those iterations should be skipped and restart the process function with the next packet.

```
def process():
    pkts = sniff(offline="infile.pcap",filter="tcp")
    out_buf = open("outfile.bin","wb")

    for pkt in pkts:
        offset = hexdump(str(pkt.payload)[:2])
        payload = hexdump(pkt.payload)

        if offset or payload is None:
            pass
        else:
            out_buf.write(two_byte_proc(payload,offset))

process()
```

Comment: What is the function `two_byte_proc`?  Where is it defined?  Also, what do you mean it doesn't work.  If it doesn't produce an error, what does it do that makes you think it's not working?

Comment: That can be rewritten as `if offset is not None and payload is not None`, too.

Comment: Or possibly `if not (offset or payload):`, which is closer to the terseness of the original. (Assuming `offset` and `payload` will never be "falsey" values like `""` that you nonetheless want to output. (If that is a problem, `if None in (offset, payload):` is also terse but clear.)

Comment: @millimoose Some iterations contain `None`, those should be skipped.

Comment: If @Martijn Pieters's answer doesn't solve the problem, you still need to explain how it's "not working".

Comment: Are you sure that those variables are None when you think they are?

Comment: At this point no, going to take this back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Astron Sorry, I got your original logic and the answers suggesting to reverse the `if` mixed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `offset or payload is None` is always True; perhaps you meant:

```
if offset is None or payload is None:
```

instead.

Since you 'pass' if that expression is True, you may as well reverse it:

```
if offset is not None and payload is not None:
    out_buf.write(two_byte_proc(payload, offset))
```

I suspect that `offset` and `payload` are either strings with length > 0 or None, in which case that can be further simplified to:

```
if offset and payload:
    out_buf.write(two_byte_proc(payload, offset))
```

Last but not least, you need to make sure that `two_byte_proc` (or `four_byte_proc` after your edit) actually *returns* something to write to out_buf. If all it returns is an empty string, for example, you won't see any results.

Comment: I updated the question with your feedback, but per the updated question, the function is not writing to file as it should be.

Comment: `offset or payload is None` is not actually always true; in particular it will be false when `offset` is false and `payload` is something other than `None`. That said, the logic is still not what is intended.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I felt that going into exacting detail about the logic of the statement was not going to help. The OP had (as do so many first-time programmers) misunderstood how logic operators combine and that was all that needs communicating.